# How can I NOT display a selected column?

Tags: powershell

I have Googled for a solution but found nothing relevant. I'm sure there is an easy way, but I would like to reformat a date column and NOT also print the original date column. What do you guys think?

Below is my (mostly) working Powershell code.

```
( Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName , InstallDate , @{ Name = "Formatted" ; Expression = { [ datetime ]:: parseexact( $_.InstallDate , 'yyyymmdd' , $null ).ToString( 'mm/dd/yy' ) } } | Where-Object { $_. InstallDate -ne $null } )
```

Comment: Just remove `InstallDate` from your `Select-Object` property list.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That is a good possibility but unfortunately when I do so the list come back empty. I think it is failing to process the requirement that "date" -ne $null.

Comment: @AdminOT, im sure that's needed due to it being piped down at the end

Comment: Move the `where-object` before the `select-object`

Comment: That works^ how hes requesting

Comment: That worked! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @AdminOfThing suggested:

```
( Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* |  Where-Object { $_. InstallDate -ne $null } )|  Select-Object DisplayName,  @{ Name = "Formatted" ; Expression = { [ datetime ]:: parseexact( $_.InstallDate , 'yyyymmdd' , $null ).ToString( 'mm/dd/yy' ) } }
```

Moving the `Where-Object` before the selection, gets the results after deleting `InstallDate`.

Answer (score 0):

Pipe to `Select-Object -ExcludeProperty`:

```
... | Where-Object { $_.InstallDate -ne $null } | Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty InstallDate
```

This will make `Select-Object` select *all* (`*`) the properties from the input object *except* for `InstallDate`

---

Alternatively, filter on `InstallDate` *before* piping to `Select-Object`:

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Where-Object { $_.InstallDate -ne $null } | Select-Object DisplayName, @{ Name = "Formatted" ; Expression = { [ datetime ]:: parseexact( $_.InstallDate , 'yyyymmdd' , $null ).ToString( 'mm/dd/yy' ) } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats one hell of a one liner you've got there.

Just add another pipe at the end and Select what you want :)
[image]

```
[code]   | Select-object -Property DisplayName,Formatted


( Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName , InstallDate , @{ Name = "Formatted" ; Expression = { [ datetime ]:: parseexact( $_.InstallDate , 'yyyymmdd' , $null ).ToString( 'mm/dd/yy' ) } } | Where-Object { $_. InstallDate -ne $null } ) | Select-object -Property DisplayName,Formatted
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer was "Move the where-object before the select-object " – AdminOfThings 5 mins ago

Thank you very much. By the way, here is the corrected code in its intended usage for basic PC info gathering:

```
[Console]::Write("Oldest program   : ");(gp HKLM:Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*|?{$_.InstallDate-ne$null}|?{$_.DisplayName-ne$null}|select @{n="n";e={[datetime]::parseexact($_.InstallDate,'yyyymmdd',$null).ToString('mm/dd/yy')}},DisplayName|Sort -Property InstallDate|select -first 1|ft -HideTableHeaders|Out-String).Trim()
```

[Console]::Write("Newest program   : ");(gp HKLM:Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall*|?{$*.InstallDate-ne$null}|?{$*.DisplayName-ne$null}|select @{n="n";e={[datetime]::parseexact($_.InstallDate,'yyyymmdd',$null).ToString('mm/dd/yy')}},DisplayName|Sort -Property InstallDate|select -last 1|ft -HideTableHeaders|Out-String).Trim()

Probably a bit of a kludge, but it does what it's supposed to do.